# Best Practice with meteor webApp to avoid xss?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using webapp to accept requests that will add items to my mongoDB instance.

This is amazing because it allows for compatibility with other services.

I currently have two questions:

1. I perform a check for all the query elements. unfortunately, regardless of how I check them, they always seem to be passed in as strings, is there any way to accept an int type or so.
2. Besides using check to verify the structure of the json query, what else can I use to avoid any cross site injections? (XSS)

This is critical for me since items in this query will pass into my DB

As mentioned above, I do use check and throw an error when the structure is not perfect, I do realize that just because the structure is correct that doesn't mean that the content cant be used to do an XSS attack

for a request such as the following

http://localhost:3000/request?token=1234567890&id=id123&timeStamp=234234&item=uy3242&anotherItem=111222

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/request', (req, res, next) => {

  //check validity of the query
  try{
    var matchTest = check(req.query, {
      token : String,
      id : String,
      timeStamp : String,
      item : String,
      anotherItem : String
    });
  }catch (err){
    res.writeHead(406);
    res.end(`request failed check`);
  }

  //check validity of the token
  try{
    //is it a good idea to use req.query.token? or should I stringify it first?
    validateToken(req.query.token);
  }
  catch(err) {
    res.writeHead(401);
    res.end(`Invalid Token`);
  }

  //finally save information needed to DB
  myCollectionName.insert(req.query);

  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(`request Passed!`);


});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a solid way to avoid xss and maybe also be able to perform checks to verify (for example, token) is actually an integer and doesnt have letters in it and so on

Comment: Question 2 is way too broad and attracts opinionated answers. Please consider reading https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) for these kind of questions Besides this each post should be focusing on one question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should escape HTML special characters `<`, `>`, `"`, `&`. Replace them with `&lt;`,`&gt;`,`&quot;`,`&amp;`.

But that [might not be enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696244/is-escaping-and-sufficient-to-block-xss-attacks). Also check [OWASP XSS cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) for potential threats.

Another great thing you can do is implement a CSP header to block all content that is not approved by what you set in it. [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) guide.
Also the [XSS-Protection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection) header can be of some help.

Second part of your question.. to verify inputs you should most likely use regex.

Comment: Is there any function available on meteorjs that would help me escape special HTML Char?

Comment: I don't think there is, either use a simple replace or search for alternatives. If you are also using other frameworks they might have something, for example React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer by cray is packed with info that sent me on the right path here.

Just to clarify for anyone who ends up landing here, I ended up using check in meteor to make sure everything i receive is a string. and is strictly within the structure I need it, ie no other query items have been added.

```
    var matchTest = check(req.query, {
      token : String,
      id : String,
      timeStamp : String,
      item : String,
      anotherItem : String
    });
```

Then I proceed to check if there are any bad characters in there using regex (its quite simple actually)

```
  try{
    var itemToCheck = "hello{console.log(\"attemptingSomething\")}";
    const pattern = /\W/g; //Checks for any non word characters, anything that is not letters or numbers
    return pattern.test(itemToCheck); //will return true if something,in this case, bad is found
  }
  catch(e){
    if(e) throw e;
  }
```